# Flex4 RichText - RangeError: Property color value 0 is out of range

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, richtext, tlf

I just migrated a Flex3 module to Flex4 since I needed to use RichText for TLF support.

However, when I run my web application I get this exception:

> RangeError: Property color value 0 is out of range
>       at flashx.textLayout.property::Property$/defaultErrorHandler()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\property\Property.as:31]
>       at flashx.textLayout.property::Property/setHelper()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\property\Property.as:230]
>       at flashx.textLayout.formats::TextLayoutFormat/setStyleByProperty()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\formats\TextLayoutFormat.as:628]
>       at flashx.textLayout.formats::TextLayoutFormat/set color()[C:\Vellum\branches\v2\2.0\dev\output\openSource\textLayout\src\flashx\textLayout\formats\TextLayoutFormat.as:957]
>       at spark.core::CSSTextLayoutFormat()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\core\CSSTextLayoutFormat.as:75]
>       at spark.components::RichText/commitProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\components\RichText.as:1039]
>       at mx.core::UIComponent/validateProperties()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\core\UIComponent.as:8209]
>       at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateClient()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:957]
>       at mx.controls::List/makeRowsAndColumns()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\List.as:1440]
>       at mx.controls.listClasses::ListBase/makeRowsAndColumnsWithExtraRows()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\listClasses\ListBase.as:1742]
>       at mx.controls.listClasses::ListBase/updateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\listClasses\ListBase.as:4383]
>       at mx.controls::List/updateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\List.as:1137]
>       at mx.controls.listClasses::ListBase/validateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\mx\src\mx\controls\listClasses\ListBase.as:3963]
>       at mx.managers::LayoutManager/validateDisplayList()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:736]
>       at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiation()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:819]
>       at mx.managers::LayoutManager/doPhasedInstantiationCallback()[E:\dev\4.5.1\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\LayoutManager.as:1180]**

The RichText is defined like this:

```
<s:RichText id="body" text="{msg}" height="30"
                       bottom="31" top="10" right="24" left="74"
                       fontSize="12" fontFamily="Verdana" 
                       paddingTop="0" paddingRight="0" paddingLeft="0"
                       direction="{rtl?'rtl':'ltr'}" />
```

It doesn't matter if I specifically define the property color.

I'm pretty much clueless to what can be wrong.

Any ideas???

Many thanks!

Ofer